# best way to access a variable exclusively

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

To using a variable mutual exclusively in MultiThreaded programs, i used to declare a static variable and in `Lock()` block change that variable.

I wonder if there is a better way to declare (for Example: an `int`) variable which should used mutually (For example: to increase and decrease an `int` variable).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: can you show your code example?

Comment: What do you mean by “better”? What kind of improvements are you looking for? Does your variable need to be `static`?

Comment: @svick i mean syntactically cleaner and ease to read with using new futures of .net 4 or 4.5.

Comment: i find Interlocked.Increment() and Interlocked.Decrement(). and i think this is a good solution to me.

Comment: The solution depends on your code. Please add your code so we will be able to assist.

Comment: @Rzassar Interlocked.Increment/Decrement is perfect if you want to increment/decrement an integer in a thread-safe manner. In most other cases you will need a different approach.

Comment: Please consider adding an answer to your own question so this question doesn't appear in unanswered lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find `Interlocked.Increment()` and `Interlocked.Decrement()`. and i think this is a good solution to me.